# Register multiple before_save conditional callbacks on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, before-save

I have two different calculations to make on my model for two different fields. Before saving.

```
Class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  #some relations
  before_save :method1, unless: :some_field_1?
  before_save :method2, unless: :some_field_2?

  def method1
    some_field_1 = some_other_field / 2
  end

  def method2
    some_field_2 = some_field_1 / 3
  end
end
```

The problem I'm having is that some_field_1 is null when method2 is called. My guess is that declaring the before_save callbacks like I'm doing is wrong.

- Does the second before_save overrides the first?
- Does the callbacks are executed in the same order in which they are declared?

I know I can wrap the two methods into one without the conditionals and problem solve, but I would prefer to have the conditional callbacks. And I want to know the correct way of doing it. The docs are not pretty clear about this.

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

For future reference. The code was Ok. The problem was somewhere else (the DB)!

Comment: I'd be very unhappy about relying on the order in which the callbacks are defined in order to do this. It's surely more robust to pop them both in a single method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does the second before_save overrides the first?

No

> Does the callbacks are executed in the same order in which they are declared?

Yes

Since your attribute is not a boolean, you probably shouldn't use the question mark. Try:

```
before_save :method1, unless: :some_field_1
before_save :method2, unless: :some_field_2
```

Comment: It seems that I was having another problem and I assumed it was because of how I was declaring the callbacks. But I've solved the other problem and the code is working! So this answer is correct. The question mark was right in place because actually the field is an integer.

Comment: @limoragni Sorry, I meant "is not a boolean".

Comment: Ah ok! So then you are right. The code is working now though. I'm going to take a look to the question mark syntax, I maybe confused about the correct use of it.

Comment: If you want it to be more explicit, you could use the `unless: "some_field_1.nil?"` or `if: "some_field_1.present?"` syntax.

Comment: I like those! Coming from a Python background I always prefer Explicit over implicit!

Answer (score 5):

You can call both of them on the same filter, separated by comma.

Ex.:

```
before_validation :t1, :t2

def t1; puts "t1"; end    
def t2; puts "t2"; end
```

Seems to be executed in this order, in my tests.

Also, from the docs (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html):

> Canceling callbacks
>
> If a before_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the
>   associated action are cancelled. If an after_* callback returns false,
>   all the later callbacks are cancelled. **Callbacks are generally run in
>   the order they are defined, with the exception of callbacks defined as
>   methods on the model, which are called last.**

If you want something done **before** the `before_save`, you might want to set one of the filters that are triggered before it, like `after_validation`, for example, to do these jobs.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But in that case I wouldn't know how to use the conditional, before_save :method1, unless: :some_field_1? which is what I am trying to preserve! Thanks!

Comment: Added some more to my response. Is that a viable option for you?

Comment: Its a useful piece of information, but I am not having problems with the callbacks being cancelled, and I do want to call the methods before_save. Thanks, but at the end the code was Ok, the problem was somewhere else. Some times when you describe the problem the solution pops up! Thanks for the response but I marked Roque Pinel answer as correct because it responds the two main questions I've made!